# Xcode 12 Storyboard Zoom Window

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode12

What is the name of this new zoom window in Xcode 12? I'm trying to hide it.

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That is the *minimap*, and you can hide it from the little popup menu at the top right of the canvas.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Updated the same with more details

Keyboards Shortcut -> Shift+Ctrl+Cmd+M

Menu Option:

Step 1. Select "Adjust Editor Option"
[image]

Step 2. Select "Minimap"
[image]